# Published a new npm package.When installed and used, SyntaxError occur : "Unexpected token"

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create an npm package that contains a React UI and some element to subscribe to an event that is sent by the UI (I am talking about Pub/Sub in that matter, the UI publishing a json and the component that would subscribe will receive it as well).So my goal is to export the UI and the subscriber element (I am using rxjs framework for publishing and subscribing if that's relevant).

When trying to import the UI using `import { chatUI } from '****';` 
where **** is the package I created.

(In the npm pacakge I exported this UI in the index.js file using:

```
import Chat from './Chat';
export var chatUI = Chat;
```

)

I encounter the following compilation error 
:

```
./node_modules/****/####/src/Chat.js
SyntaxError: D:\container\‏‏R (3)\node_modules\****\###\src\Chat.js: Unexpected token (406:6)

  404 | 
  405 |     return (
> 406 |       <div className="chat">
      |       ^
  407 |         <h3 key={uuidv1()}>
  408 |           Title<h4>.</h4>
  409 |         </h3>
```

This UI works just fine by itself but yielding a compilation error when it's imported from the npm package.. I am new to publishing an npm packages so I am pretty sure I am missing some pieces here..

**Edit:** based on answer suggestion, after using `npx babel src/App.js --out-file script-compiled2.js`
I am getting the following error:`src/App.js: Unexpected token (9:6)`.

Similar thing occur in the chat.js component after trying to compile with babel, while files without html tags seems to compile ok..

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Chat from './Chat';

const App = class extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { title } = this.context;
    return (
      <div className="center-screen">
        {title} <Chat />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Depending on how you create your react app, if you use CRA it won't transpile anything inside `node_modules` so you will have to pretranspile your component before publishing

Comment: @Dominkin I did use CRA . Can you explain how can I do that ?

Comment: I have added an answer below. Please mark it as solved if this was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-transpile your component before you publish it to the registry to make sure CRA can use the code.
One way to do this is to create a `lib/` folder and transpile your files into there via the [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) `--out-file` option.
Then point your `main` inside your `package.json` file to `lib/` instead of `src/` or wherever you files currently are.

Comment: @Dominkin I tried "npx babel src/Chat.js --out-file script-compiled3.js" in addition to the index.js and App.js that I have in my project, and I am getting something similar in the terminal : "src/Chat.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (152:13)" it happened in App.js too and they both contains html tags. obviously compiling index.js by itself doesn't do anything

Comment: Ok, but two files (at least) are unable to compile due to this "Unexpected token" error.. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: If babel can't transpile your code you may have a syntax error in there... can you include the code of said component?

Comment: I edited the question to include one of the components that yield an error, though the project by itself starting and functioning fine